# Test google pay with stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, google-pay

I integrated google pay with stripe and configured test environment in google pay and stripe . Now i want to test it , its not accepting stripe test card to my google pay . Is there any specific test card for google pay ? Is it ok to add original card? , Are they going to charge any money in test environment?

Comment: Yep, you have to use a real card to be able to add it to your Google Pay wallet. But in test mode, Stripe won't actually charge it.

Comment: Can you add that as answer so i will accept it

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70535222/12585274

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use our **real** card for testing, but in Google-Pay's **test** mode and/or environment no amount will be charged.

(**For India there will be a charge of $1,** but in few minutes it reversed back into the same account.)

Comment: It shows that unrecognized app .Please make sure to test the app with payment. Please can u help me out.how to make the payment in test mode

Comment: Before you publish you need to submit to google support team for approval. Please contact google support team for it.

Comment: For testing Purpose  also,  we need to send the apk to google

Comment: Testing we can do no problem but when we want to release our app should pass googles test , otherwise it will show unrecognized app.

Comment: I have given a real card in testing but still,  it shows me request failed error. Today we have a beta release. Please, can u say how long it takes?

Comment: Rakki s How many days it takes to get the live access. Can you give full detail procedure? Can you contact me with these mail: lahariareti10@gmail.com. Because it is very Important. For these, we delayed for our Production. Can You help me out without any hesitation? Thanks

Comment: Time is based on google support team and how good you followed google recommendation .Procedure is  send apk in test environment to google team they will ask live once your test environment apk pass test . Once google checked and confirmed your app can go to production.

Comment: Rakki can you please help me? I integrate google pay in my android app with the stripe. In the test environment, I test it with a stripe sample card. but it shows invalid payment method error. how can I fix it?

Comment: One more thing, in google validation procedure they ask a merchant name, what is it?

Comment: @RosemaryRajan Please read the answer , you can use your real card not stripe test card. All you have to check is google pay should be test environment .

Comment: they ask a merchant id, what is it?@Rakki s

Comment: Sorry i have no idea about merchant id .

Answer (score 1):

The Google Pay API now supports [test cards from your PSPs](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/test-card-suite#gateway-test-cards). Add configuration for your payment gateway under the `tokenizationSpecification` parameter, when you use Google Pay in `TEST` mode and you'll be able to complete successful and filed payment flows.

Answer (score 0):

```
val googlePayLauncher = GooglePayPaymentMethodLauncher(
            activity = this,
            config = GooglePayPaymentMethodLauncher.Config(
                environment = GooglePayEnvironment.Test,
                merchantCountryCode = "IN",
                merchantName = "merchantName"
            ),
            readyCallback = ::onGooglePayReady,
            resultCallback = ::onGooglePayResult
        )
```

**GooglePayEnvironment.Test** test mode no amount will be charged

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).