# I want to connect Google Pay with Stripe in my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, payment, google-pay

I want to use [Google Pay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Pay_(payment_method)) in my app and I want to get my money in the Stripe dashboard.

I try the Flutter pay package, and now I am able to see the Google Pay sheet.

I am an Indian citizen, so I am not able to test Google Pay global in India, so how can I test my app? And I don't know how Google Pay responds when payment is a success.

Please attach some documentation or some example to integrate Google Pay with Stripe in Flutter.

I use this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/pay

Here is my code for open Google Pay sheet:

```
import 'package:pay/pay.dart' as pay;

Widget _paymentOptions() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        pay.GooglePayButton(
          paymentConfigurationAsset: PaymentJson.googlePay,
          paymentItems: _paymentItems,
          width: 300,
          style: pay.GooglePayButtonStyle.black,
          type: pay.GooglePayButtonType.pay,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
          onPaymentResult: (val) {
            log(val.toString(), name: "Google Pay");
          },
          loadingIndicator: const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ),
        pay.ApplePayButton(
          paymentConfigurationAsset: PaymentJson.applePay,
          paymentItems: _paymentItems,
          width: 300,
          style: pay.ApplePayButtonStyle.black,
          type: pay.ApplePayButtonType.buy,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
          onPaymentResult: (val) {
            log(val.toString(), name: "Apple Pay");
          },
          childOnError: const Text(
            "Apple pay Not Available Now",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          onError: (e) {
            print(e);
            showAppSnackBar("Google pay Not Available Now");
          },
          loadingIndicator: const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }


  final _paymentItems = [
    pay.PaymentItem(
      label: 'Total',
      amount: '99.99',
      status: pay.PaymentItemStatus.final_price,
    )
  ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this: *[Pay Plugin support](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe#pay-plugin-support)*

It's the Stripe package and it fully supports the Pay plugin.

Comment: in this plugin documentation they mention use pay plugin for google pay but I don't know how to connect stripe with google pay

Comment: in the link above the pay plugin support have a code snippet for a function, this function should be called in your code here

onPaymentResult: (val) {
// onGooglePayResult(val);            
log(val.toString(), name: "Google Pay");
          },

then your google pay is integrated with stripe and will pass the payment data to Stripe so it can be viewed in Stripe dashboard

Comment: can you share any reference?

Comment: here is Stripe example code for apple pay: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example/lib/screens/wallets/apple_pay_screen.dart

and here is for google pay: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example/lib/screens/wallets/google_pay_screen.dart

you have the whole repo full of code examples for different payment gateways and platforms

Answer (score 2):

You can test Google Pay using test cards by following the instructions outlined at *[Test card suite](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/test-card-suite)* or *[Testing Google Pay integrations without a debit or credit card #70](https://github.com/google-pay/google-pay-button/discussions/70)*.

It involves joining the [`googlepay-test-mode-stub-data`](https://groups.google.com/g/googlepay-test-mode-stub-data/about) Google group and using the integration in `TEST` mode (i.e., `environment` set to `TEST`).

Comment: this link is not able to give me test credit card for google pay ca you share other references?

Comment: Are you able to visit https://groups.google.com/g/googlepay-test-mode-stub-data/about and click the _Join group_ button? Once you've done that, using Google Pay on a test integration should show the test cards. Here is a test integration you should be able to use: https://paydemo.withgoogle.com/detail/mens_outerwear/Anvil+L+S+Crew+Neck+-+Grey